# TTFB very long when adding custom php function to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, rest, api

I am using Wordpress REST API to create content displayed in the iOS and Android app.

Since WP only shows 10 posts in the REST API, I have made a u custom php function to display more and that code causes a very long TTFB time.

I contacted server support and they sent the errors received when trying to access the WP REST API endpoint

This is their response:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("139.162.182.238")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT|POLLWRNORM}], 1, 299996) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT|POLLWRNORM}])
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
sendto(3, "HEAD /wp-json/wp/v2/test_odgovor"..., 200, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 200
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
```

Below is the code I use to show more than 10 posts in REST API:

```
add_filter( 'rest_endpoints', function( $endpoints ){
    if ( ! isset( $endpoints['/wp/v2/test_odgovor'] ) ) {
        return $endpoints;
    }
    unset( $endpoints['/wp/v2/test_odgovor'][0]['args']['per_page'] ['maximum'] );
    return $endpoints;
});
add_filter( 'rest_endpoints', function( $endpoints ){
      if ( ! isset( $endpoints['/wp/v2/test_odgovor'] ) ) {
        return $endpoints;
      }
    $endpoints['/wp/v2/test_odgovor'][0]['args']['per_page']['default'] = 2000;
    return $endpoints;
});
```

Is there any other function that can help to show more WP posts in the API, or should I change the server?

I am not familiar with server errors so I don't know what could I do here. Should I change the code in app and load the JSON differently?

EDIT -  So it seems that the upgrading Wordpress to version 5 caused this problem. When I downgraded it to 4.9 TTFB was below 4 seconds. Does anyone have an idea why would newer version of Wordpress cause this?

Any advice is welcome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid TTFB problem, you need to finish the server side work faster. Fetching 2000 posts in one query seems to be a time taking process. Increase this value gradually like 20, 30, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, do you have an example on how could I do this?